# Reset store after logout with Apollo client

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to reset the store after logout in my react-apollo application.

So I've created a method called "logout" which is called when I click on a button (and passed by the 'onDisconnect' props).

To do that I've tried to follow this example :
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html

But in my case I want LayoutComponent as HOC (and it's without graphQL Query).

Here is my component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withApollo, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';

import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Sidebar from 'Sidebar/Sidebar';
import RightMenu from 'RightMenu/RightMenu';

class Layout extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);        
}

logout = () => {
    client.resetStore();
    alert("YOUHOU");
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar title="myApp" iconElementRight={<RightMenu onDisconnect={ this.logout() } />} />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default withApollo(Layout);
```

The issue here is that 'client' is not defined and I can't logout properly. 
Do you have any idea to help me to handle this situation or an example/best practices to logout from apollo client ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Finally it was just necessary to add this.props.client.resetStore to reset the store properly...

Comment: `client.resetStore()` doesn't actually reset the store. It refetches all active queries.

Comment: You're right for the refetch of all active queries but it seems that the store is truly reset with this method, as I read in apollo graphql documentation : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html#login-logout

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you need to clear your cache and don't want to fetch all active queries you can use:

`client.cache.reset()`

`client` being your Apollo client.

Keep in mind that this will NOT trigger the `onResetStore` event.

Comment: None of these work for me, the data still persists inside my client cache.

Answer (score 15):

> client.resetStore() doesn't actually reset the store. It refetches all
>   active queries

Above statement is very correct.

I was also having the logout related problem. After using `client.resetStore()` It refetched all pending queries, so if you logout the user and remove session token after logout you will get authentication errors.

I used below approach to solve this problem -

```
<Mutation
    mutation={LOGOUT_MUTATION} 
                onCompleted={()=> {
                  sessionStorage.clear()
                  client.clearStore().then(() => {
                    client.resetStore();
                    history.push('/login')
                  });
                }}
              >
                {logout => (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      logout();
                    }}
                  >
                    Logout <span>{user.userName}</span>
                  </button>
                )}
              </Mutation>
```

Important part is this function -

```
onCompleted={()=> {
                  sessionStorage.clear(); // or localStorage
                  client.clearStore().then(() => {
                    client.resetStore();
                    history.push('/login') . // redirect user to login page
                  });
                }}
```

Answer (score 15):

you can use `useApolloClient` to access apollo client.

```
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/client";

const client = useApolloClient();

client.clearStore();
```

Answer (score 7):

You were very close!

Instead of *client.resetStore()* it should have been **this.props.client.resetStore()**

> [withApollo()](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#withapollocomponent) will create a new component which passes in an instance
>   of ApolloClient as a client prop.

```
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';

class Layout extends Component {
  ...
  logout = () => {
    this.props.client.resetStore();
    alert("YOUHOU");
  }
  ...
}

export default withApollo(Layout);
```

For those unsure about the differences between **resetStore** and **clearStore**:

[resetStore()](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.resetStore)

> Resets your entire store by clearing out your cache and then
>   re-executing all of your active queries. This makes it so that you may
>   guarantee that there is no data left in your store from a time before
>   you called this method.

[clearStore()](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.clearStore)

> Remove all data from the store. Unlike resetStore, clearStore will not
>   refetch any active queries.

Comment: withApollo is deprecated. 
Use useApolloClient now.