# Clearing cache on logout with Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to clear caches so I get data from new user, not one that logged out..

In documentation Apollo recommends `clearStore()`, but it seems like it doesn't work..

I tried this way:

```
handleLogout = () => {
  const { client } = this.props;
  localStorage.clear();
  client.clearStore().then(() => {
    history.push('/login')
  })
}
```

`clearStore()` returns Promise so I did it this way, I tried also call the function but same thing

Comment: Perhaps it's throwing an error? What happens if you add a `.catch(console.log)` to the end of the Promise chain?

Comment: No error, it redirects but cache is not cleared..

Comment: did you check localstorage is actually empty?

Answer (score 4):

You can call the cache store and reset is using the below:

```html
handleLogout = () => {
        const { client } = this.props;

        client.cache.reset().then(() => {
            history.push('/login')
        })
```

Comment: Is this of any help @merko? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887480/reset-store-after-logout-with-apollo-client

Comment: @merko If you haven't found an answer yet, the way that I've gotten it to work is to use `client.resetStore();` This is part of the client object.

Comment: only worked for me using client.cache.reset(). Thanks @jake