# Apollo client JWT token is only attached after refresh

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, apollo-client

I'm saving the authorization token from the graphql server on localStorage, and attach the token to authorization header. But after login, which saves the token to the localStorage, server gets authorization header with null token value. However, I can check the token exists on localStorage by browser's developer mode. After refreshing the page, the server gets normal authorization header. How can make my apollo client to send right header on the first try? Following is my apollo client generator.

```
export default new ApolloClient({
  uri: "MYSERVERENDPOINT",
  clientState: {
    defaults,
    resolvers
  },
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you get item from localStorage, you better do it with async/await to make sure getting the item before return it.

Try to make a seperated func to get item synchronosly and return a string literal and put it into header.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but I was having this problem too and found these

- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#reset-store-on-logout
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204972/13491532

You can just call

```
client.clearStore();
```

and if you need help importing the client

```
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/client";

const client = useApolloClient();
```

Answer (score -1):

You must manually reload the page in code.

Try :
`window.location.reload()`