# Apollo client not sending token to backend until page refresh

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've been working on an app and only realized this issue when I started to clear the cache, but my app only works fine on refresh. When I clear all the cache, refresh then run through my app, I realized that my queries were returning my custom error "GraphQL error: Not authenticated as user".

I believe something is wrong with the way that I've set up my apollo client. It seems that the context is being set **as soon as it's instantiated** and then never changes the context even if the token exists. It would also explain why after logging in then refreshing, the queries work with the token until the local storage/cache is cleared. So my question is what's wrong with what I have?

````
import { persistCache } from "apollo-cache-persist";

import { ISLOGGEDIN_QUERY } from "./components/gql/Queries"

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
persistCache({
    cache,
    storage: localStorage
})
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    cache,
    resolvers: {
        Mutation: {
            changeValue: (_, args, { cache }) => {
                const { isAuth } = token ? cache.readQuery({ query: ISLOGGEDIN_QUERY }) : false;
                cache.writeData({
                    data: { isAuth: !isAuth }
                })
                return null;
            }
        }
    },

    request: (operation) => {
        operation.setContext({
            headers: {
                authorization: token ? token : ''
            }
        })
    },
});

//set default values
client.cache.writeData({ data: { isAuth: token ? true : false } })


export default client;```
````

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but I was having this problem too and found these

- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#reset-store-on-logout
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204972/13491532

You can just call clear store after your login mutation

```
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/client";

const client = useApolloClient();

client.clearStore();
```